# How to call REST API which supports RQL (Resource Query Language) using Java

Tags: java, api, rest

I am trying to consume REST API using Java. Using Oauth1 for authentication. Code block is given below-

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import javax.swing.text.html.FormSubmitEvent;

public class Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken {
    private OAuthConsumer oAuthConsumer;

    public Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken() {
        String consumerKey = "my_consumer_key";
        String consumerSecret = "my_consumer_secret";
        setupContext(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    }

    public void setupContext(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret) {
        this.oAuthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        //oAuthConsumer.setTokenWithSecret("", "");
        oAuthConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new AuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());
    }

    public void authorize(HttpRequestBase httpRequest)  {
        try {
            oAuthConsumer.sign(httpRequest);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {

        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {

        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {

        }
    }

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(FormSubmitEvent.MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/json");

        try {
            authorize(httpRequest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url="https:host/order-manager/orders";
        //url="https:host/order-manager/orders?in(internalId,12345)";
        Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken withoutDevkitClient = new Oauth1RestCallWithOutToken();
        withoutDevkitClient.executeGetRequest(url);
    }

}
```

Dependencies-

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I am getting successful response if consuming URL like- "**https:host/order-manager/orders**".
But I am getting 500 response if consuming URL like- "**https:host/order-manager/orders?in(internalId,12345)**" which contains RQL params. Both URLs are working fine while consuming from Postman or Insomnia.
Can you please help me to point out my mistake? Or any suggestions to consume RQL supported REST API using java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution. Code is given below-

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthHmacSigner;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth.OAuthParameters;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import javax.swing.text.html.FormSubmitEvent;

public class Oauth1RQLRestCallWithOutToken {
    private final String consumerKey = "consumerKey";
    private final String consumerSecret = "consumerSecret";

    public void executeGetRequest(String customURIString){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", "UTF-8");

        HttpRequestBase httpRequest = null;
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = new URI(customURIString);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String methodtype = "GET";

        if (methodtype.equals(FormSubmitEvent.MethodType.GET.toString())) {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(uri);
        }

        httpRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        httpRequest.addHeader("Accept","application/json");

        //Generate Authorization header
        try{
            String headerValue=getAuthorizationHeader(customURIString,methodtype);
            httpRequest.setHeader("Authorization",headerValue);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
        }


        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpHost target = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), -1, uri.getScheme());
            httpResponse = client.execute(target, httpRequest);
            System.out.println("Connection status : " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());

            InputStream inputStraem = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStraem, writer, "UTF-8");
            String output = writer.toString();

            System.out.println(output);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private  String getAuthorizationHeader(String url, String method) throws Exception {
        OAuthParameters oauthParams = new OAuthParameters();
        oauthParams.version = "1.0";
        oauthParams.consumerKey = consumerKey;
        oauthParams.computeNonce();
        oauthParams.computeTimestamp();

        OAuthHmacSigner oauthSigner = new OAuthHmacSigner();
        oauthSigner.clientSharedSecret = consumerSecret;

        oauthParams.signer = oauthSigner;
        oauthParams.computeSignature(method,
                new GenericUrl(url)
        );

        return oauthParams.getAuthorizationHeader();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url="https:host/order-manager/orders";
        url="https:hosts/order-manager/orders?in(internalId,12345)";
        Oauth1RQLRestCallWithOutToken rqlRestCallWithOutToken = new Oauth1RQLRestCallWithOutToken();
        rqlRestCallWithOutToken.executeGetRequest(url);
    }    
}
```

Dependencies-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.38.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.quickbooks-online</groupId>
            <artifactId>ipp-v3-java-devkit</artifactId>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
            <version> 6.0.7 </version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```